# Cannot access the domain name under the cellular network, and it returns to normal after turning on/off the airplane mode

Tags: okhttp, cellular-network, cfnetwork

On IOS devices, the system browser cannot access this website;
On Android devices, use OKHttp library cannot access this website too;

when use WI-FI network, it worker nornal ;but return to cellular network， stilled failed